# Bootstrap complex column position ordering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to `pull/push divs of a column` from `another column` in Bootstrap grid system? For example:

At desktop view: it's like this way:

```
Parent Column 1 | Parent Column 2
First Content   | Second Content
Third Content   | Fourth Content
```

At mobile view, it's like this way:

```
Parent Column 1
First Content
Second Content
Parent Column 2
Third Content
Fourth Content
```

Please take a look on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2g4zn5u/2/) to understand what I am trying to mean.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by using bootstrap's grid.

```css
.first {
  background: yellow;
  height: 300px;
}
.second {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}
.third {
  background: green;
  height: 300px;
  color: white;
}
.fourth {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 first">
      FIRST
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 second">
      SECOND
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 third">
      THIRD
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 fourth">
      FOURTH
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use [Masonry JS](http://masonry.desandro.com/):

```js
var $container = $('.masonry-container');
$container.masonry({
  columnWidth: '.item',
  itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

```css
.first {
  background: yellow;
  height: 300px;
}
.second {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}
.third {
  background: green;
  height: 300px;
  color: white;
}
.fourth {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.1.1/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row masonry-container">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 first item">
      FIRST
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 second item">
      SECOND
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 third item">
      THIRD
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 fourth item">
      FOURTH
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At large screen, it's looking like this: http://i.imgur.com/bsobN7g.png

Comment: Thanks! But, I think I will need "Third" div below "First" div and "Fourth" div below "Second" div for Desktop view.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is more of a float problem because your columns have variable height. Create a special class to pull the 2nd and 3rd columnd right on larger screens..

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .pull-md-right {
        float:right;
    }
}
```

And, use it like this..

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="first">First</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 pull-md-right">
            <div class="second">Second</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 pull-md-right">
            <div class="third">Third</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="fourth">Fourth</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/CYteNdheKS

In Bootstrap 4, [responsive floats](http://codeply.com/go/zRh6njYSux) are included so you won't need the extra CSS.

Comment: Nice solution! But, I think I will need "Third" div below "First" div and "Fourth" div below "Second" div for Desktop view.